# MySQL - Performing a COUNT(*) for the current row

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT col1, col3, col5, col8
FROM Table1
```

In my `SELECT` query, I want to perform a COUNT(*) **exclusively for the current row**.

I want something like this, but have no idea how I can get this:

```
SELECT col1, col3, 
(
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table1 WHERE col3 = col3 value for current row
), 
col5, col8
FROM Table1
```

What is the correct way to perform a COUNT(*) for the current row of a `SELECT` query resultset?

Comment: Count of the current row??? That's too confusing.

Comment: count of each row is 1 if id is unique, are you tiring to fine the duplicate ids?

Comment: is Id of this table auto increment or unique or just value??

Comment: Very complex problem. A SELECT query will get you a couple of row. What I want is this: I want to have the count(*) of my table for the 1st, then second, then 3rd row and so on. This result should be included in another column. Complex indeed.

Comment: are you trying to sum up all the values in col1, col3, col5 and col8?

Comment: I think I misexplained my problem. Let me edit my question.

Comment: Why don't you describe the actual problem you have, with real names, sample data and expected output? Your pseudo-code only leads to endless speculation.

Comment: Vote this question to be closed. It was a very poorly explained problem. Flag it as "Unclear what you're asking."

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
set @num := 0;
SELECT @num := @num+1 , col1, col3, col5, col8 FROM Table1
```

or other way:

```
SET @num := ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM Table1) ;
SELECT @num := @num -1 , col1, col3, col5, col8
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT col1, col3, 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM table1 WHERE id = A.Id
) Count, 
col5, col8
FROM Table1 A
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

If I write my query like this:

```
SELECT col1, col3, 
COUNT(*) AS count,
col5, col8
FROM Table1
```

then I get COUNT of all the items in Table1 for all rows.

I actually wanted COUNT of all items for selective rows.

Like I may have col3 value appearing more than once. I actually want the count of all items for each col3.

So, `GROUP BY` clause is the solution.

```
SELECT col1, col3, 
COUNT(*) AS Count, 
col5, col8
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY col3
```

Sorry, I think I wasn't able to explain my problem properly, so it confused a lot of people.. A very poor question. My bad.